# Push notification when email/SMS received

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am attempting to figure out the easiest way to tackle a relatively complex objective.

I am writing an iOS app for my volunteer fire station.  When every emergency call goes out, all members receive an SMS (or email) with a predetermined structure giving call details.  I want to parse this message and generate a station-to-call route.

I can generate the map with no problem.  The issue lies in getting the message to the app.  I know iOS can not read incoming texts or emails.  The next option is to set up a server to receive the messages and push notifications to all members.  However, I know push notifications have problems and likely won't be as fast as we would require.  So, is there another way?  Can I get the app to receive its own emails, separate from the Mail app?

Thank you!

Comment: what let you think that push notification are not fast enough? email notifications are also push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Individual apps do not have access to Mail and SMS. The only way to do what you want to do is send a push notification. You could send custom data that contains the latitude and longitude of the location of the call which would allow your app to plot a route.

I have played with push notifications and most of the time they are FAST, and emails use the same system. There are some connectivity situations where a push message will be faster than an SMS and others where an SMS will be faster than a push. Also, Apple does not guarantee delivery of Push Notifications, so for that reason it is not a good idea for emergency services to rely on them.

In fact, according to the Apple App Submission guidelines (which you have to have an apple developer account to read in full) `Apps that use location-based APIs for dispatch, fleet management, or emergency services will be rejected.`

So be aware of this.